# How to add an active spring profile from an environment variable?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-profiles

Until now, I'm setting the following environment variable in my `~/.bash_profile` :

```
export SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=local
```

This set my active spring profile. But now, I want to **add** the local profile to other profiles defined in `application.properties` and not **replace** them.

In the [Spring Boot documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html#boot-features-adding-active-profiles), there is a section about adding active profile, but I see nothing about adding active profile from an environment variable.

I've tried to set the `SPRING_PROFILES_INCLUDE` environment variable, but this has no effect.

How to do this?

P.S.: I'm using Spring Boot 1.4.2.

Comment: have you tried utilizing ConfigurableEnvironment http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/ConfigurableEnvironment.html

Comment: No, I didn't, but I prefer to use a solution such as the Olszewski one.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**With default addition profile**

You can introduce your own environment variable in the `application.properties` file, next to the defined profiles using an expression. For instance, if your current file looks like this:

```
spring.profiles.active=profile1,profile2
```

with a custom environment variable it will change into:

```
spring.profiles.active=profile1,profile2,${ADDITIONAL_APP_PROFILES:local}
```

where `ADDITIONAL_APP_PROFILES` is the name of the environment variable which you set instead of `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE`.

The value `local` is used when the variable is not set on a current environment. In that case, the profile called `local` will be activated. If you don't set the default value and the environment variable is not present, the whole expression will be used as the name of an active profile.

**Without default addition profile**

If you like to avoid activating the default profile, you can remove the placeholder value and the comma before the variable expression:

```
spring.profiles.active=profile1,profile2${ADDITIONAL_APP_PROFILES}
```

but in that case the variable set on a current environment have to start with a comma:

```
export ADDITIONAL_APP_PROFILES=,local
```

Answer (score 13):

The next sentence in the documentation you linked to:

> Sometimes it is useful to have profile-specific properties that add to the active profiles rather than replace them. The `spring.profiles.include` property can be used to unconditionally add active profiles.

So you can launch your application with a command-line parameter:

```sh
-Dspring.profiles.include=${SPRING_PROFILES_INCLUDE}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of **adding** a programmatically additional active profile from system env or jvm arg.

```
@Configuration
public class ApplicationInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer, ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableWebApplicationContext> {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        servletContext.setInitParameter("contextInitializerClasses", this.getClass().getCanonicalName());
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(ConfigurableWebApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        ConfigurableEnvironment environment = applicationContext.getEnvironment();
        environment.addActiveProfile(System.getProperty("myProperty"));
        environment.addActiveProfile(System.getEnv("myProperty"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is not the Spring way, but also could be useful in some cases.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.setProperty("spring.profiles.active", "local");
    SpringApplication.run(MainApplication.class, args);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

To support bash environment,  available values are **SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE** and **SPRING_PROFILES_DEFAULT**

not, SPRING_PROFILES_INCLUDE

you probably have to resort commandline way -Dspring.profiles.include or pro grammatically workout with [ConfigurableEnvironment](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/ConfigurableEnvironment.html)

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/AbstractEnvironment.html#ACTIVE_PROFILES_PROPERTY_NAME

Comment: Sorry, but I only understand half of your post. Could you please rephrase it?